# Example of a relation on a finite set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

In one of the exercises, I proved that $R^n+1\subseteq R^n$ for all $n \ge1$

But now I need to give an example of relation on finite set such that $R^3 \subsetneq R^2 $

Here $R^3$ =$R \circ R \circ R$  and similarly $R^2 = R \circ R$   i.e. composition

So can anyone give an of a relation $R$ on a finite set such that $R^3 \subsetneq R^2 $.
given that $R$ is transitive.

Comment: HINT: Look at the relation $<$ (**not** $\le$) on a finite set of integers.

Comment: You’re welcome!